# Google Chrome App To Link to Another Website? Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I keep getting errors and am not sure what I am doing wrong. If anyone can help me resolve it, I would appreciate it. This is using Manifest V3. Here is my background.js:

It keeps breaking at the code below:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
func: () => location.href = "THE URL"
```

});

```js
// Extension event listeners are a little different from the patterns you may have seen in DOM or
// Node.js APIs. The below event listener registration can be broken in to 4 distinct parts:
//
// * chrome      - the global namespace for Chrome's extension APIs
// * runtime     – the namespace of the specific API we want to use
// * onInstalled - the event we want to subscribe to
// * addListener - what we want to do with this event
//
// See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/events/ for additional details.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {

    // While we could have used `let url = "hello.html"`, using runtime.getURL is a bit more robust as
    // it returns a full URL rather than just a path that Chrome needs to be resolved contextually at
    // runtime.
    let url = "https://www.globalflyerdistribution.com/"

    // Open a new tab pointing at our page's URL using JavaScript's object initializer shorthand.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015
    //
    // Many of the extension platform's APIs are asynchronous and can either take a callback argument
    // or return a promise. Since we're inside an async function, we can await the resolution of the
    // promise returned by the tabs.create call. See the following link for more info on async/await.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await
    
    let tab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url });

    
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        func: () => location.href = "THE URL"
      }); 
  
    // Finally, let's log the ID of the newly created tab using a template literal.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
    //
    // To view this log message, open chrome://extensions, find "Hello, World!", and click the
    // "service worker" link in the card to open DevTools.
    console.log(`Created tab ${tab.id}`);
  });
```

Comment: It should be chrome.scripting.executeScript not chrome.tabs but it's still wrong to use to redirect the URL because the correct method is chrome.tabs.update. What is the overall goal/scenario you want to implement?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I would simply like to make the Chrome app link to the URL. I could try chrome.tabs.update